# How to determine next custom post in hierarchy

Tags: custom-post-types

I need to find the **next custom post type** in hierarchy after **current post type**.

Is there any method through which I can detect it.

Let me explain this in bit with an example

I have a custom type named portfolio. and I have 20 entries into it.

Now I want to code it in such a way that if I select any one custom post type viz, posttype having id 20, in wp_post table then in this case I want to search the next id in wp_post table that will have similar post_type value'portfolio'.

If you can help me with a solution or idea it will be good.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please clarify your need.

Comment: question edited

Comment: Inside the loop or outside the loop ?

Comment: Anywhere I want database query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I've written a SQL based function for you-

```
function the_dramatist_get_last_post($current_post_type = 'viz', $other_post_type = 'portfolio', $post_id = '', $prev = true) {
    global $wpdb;
    $order_by = $prev ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
    $sign = $prev ? '<' : '>';
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS p
                            WHERE p.post_type != %s
                            AND p.post_type LIKE %s
                            AND p.id {$sign} %d
                            ORDER BY id {$order_by}
                            LIMIT 1",
            array(
                $current_post_type,
                $other_post_type,
                $post_id
            )
    );

    return $wpdb->get_results($sql);
}
```

Use it like `the_dramatist_get_last_post('viz', 'portfolio', 559, false)`. It'll give you both previous and next post based on the last parameter `$prev`. If `$prev` is `true` then it'll give you previous and if `false` then it'll give you the next post. Rest of the parameters uses is too simple. Hope you'll understand those easily.